# Building dependencies by a recursive call to make?

Tags: c, makefile

I've read some articles explaining how recursive makefiles were evil in the case of compiling projects with subdirectories.

But, I found this handy way to automatically generate dependencies

```
exec = main
objs  = main.o A.o B.o C.o   # main and object modules

deps = $(objs:.o=.d)         # dependencies file

all: $(deps)
    $(MAKE) $(exec)

-include $(deps)

%.d: %.c                        # how to build dependency files
    $(CC) -MM $(CFLAGS) $< > $@

main: $(objs)          # How to build the main exec
```

Building the target "all" updates the dependency files if needed, and then considers rebuilding the main exec if needed.

Is there something fundamentally flawed with this approach?

Comment: Just a note about the "considered harmful" paper: many people take the headline and assume recursion should never be used, but that's not actually what the paper talks about.  It discusses how splitting your dependency graph into multiple makefiles is bad.  However, in some cases recursion doesn't do that (for example, in your situation you're building a suite of prerequisites separate from the main objects).  Recursion can be a powerful tool and shouldn't just be tossed based on a headline... as with most powerful tools there's a right and wrong way to use it.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using GNU make, this hack is unnecessary. GNU make is [smart enough](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Prerequisites.html) to automatically rebuild any (make)file that is included, and then restart itself:

> Since the ‘.d’ files are makefiles like any others, make will remake them as necessary with no further work from you. See [Remaking Makefiles](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Remaking-Makefiles.html).

About other make implementations, the GNU make manual has this to say:

> With old make programs, it was traditional practice to use [the -M] compiler feature to generate prerequisites on demand with a command like ‘make depend’. That command would create a file depend containing all the automatically-generated prerequisites; then the makefile could use include to read them in (see [Include](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html)).

Comment: A more modern/efficient method of dependency generation, which doesn't even rely on this feature of GNU make, is described here: http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/

Answer (score 0):

As remarked by other contributors, gnu make treats .d dependencies files as Makefile and rebuilds them automagically when needed.

This makes the recursive call unnecessary, and the question  falls flat.

Of course, as usual, "considered harmful" paper titles have to be read with a grain of salt, if really read at all, from a long tradition (Knuth's "rebuttal" of Dijkstra's paper cites Disjktra own fear to be believed as terribly dogmatic" and "others making a religion of it". "Fanatical advocates going over the board" !).